# Seed Code First Many-to-Many off of a Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working with Entity Framework using the code-first approach. I have successfully seeded data for a many-to-many relationship (Type to Status). Now I need to seed data for a many-to-many relationship between Status and SubStatus.

I first create all the statuses, and then I add each Type and add the many-to-many relationship with each status.

Here is what I have for Type and Status:

```
    IList<Status> statuses = new List<Status>();

    statuses .Add(new Status() { Value = "On" });
    statuses .Add(new Status() { Value = "Off" });

    foreach (Status s in statuses)
    {
        context.Set<Status>().AddOrUpdate(s);
    }

    Type type1 = new Type()
    {
        Value = "Type 1",
        Status = new List<Status>()  
        {
            statuses.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Value == "On"),
            statuses.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Value == "Off")
        }
    };
    Type type2 = new Type() 
    { 
        Value = "Type 2", 
        Status = new List<Status>()  
        {
            statuses.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Value == "On"),
        }
    };
```

How can I build off of this to then add the many-to-many relationship between Status and SubStatus now?

Here's a list of a couple of SubStatuses:

```
  IList<SubStatus> subStatuses = new List<SubStatus>();
  subStatuses.Add(new SubStatus() { Value = "Success" });
  subStatuses.Add(new SubStatus() { Value = "Fail" });

   foreach (SubStatus s in subStatuses)
   {
       context.Set<SubStatus>().AddOrUpdate(s);
   }
```

Comment: I don't understand where you're having the problem. Just make sure all the collections contain the right entities and you don't have different instances representing the same entity.

Comment: I am having trouble adding the many-to-many between Status and SubStatus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a parent / child relationship? You could restructure your `Status` entity like this and remove the `SubSatus` class:

```
public class Type
{
     public string Value {get;set;}
     public ICollection<Status> Statuses {get;set;}
{

public class Status
{
      public string Value {get;set;}
      public int? ParentStatusId {get;set;}
      public Status ParentStatus {get;set;}
      public ICollection<Status> ChildStatuses {get;set;}
      Public ICollection<Type> Types {get;set;}

}
```

Then you can append `ChildStatuses` and associate them with a `ParentStatus`

```
var typeA = new Type()
            {
               Value = "Type A"
            };

var typeB = new Type()
            {
               Value = "Type B"
            };
var statuses = new List<Status>(){
                     new Status()
                     {
                         Value = "On",
                         ChildStatuses = new List<Status>(){
                                               new Status()
                                               {
                                                  Value = "Success",
                                                  Types = new List<Type>()
                                                          {
                                                            typeA,
                                                            typeB
                                                          }
                                               },
                                               new Status()
                                               {
                                                  Value = "Fail",
                                                  Types = new List<Type>()
                                                          {
                                                            typeB

                                                          }
                                               }
                     }
                   };


context.Set<Status>().AddOrUpdate(s => s.Value, statuses.ToArray() );
```

Comment: But then how do I add the many-to many between Status and Type?

Comment: @JAck28, I updated the answer, you would put a collection of Types on a Status object. When you are seeding, I would create each status  and type separately, then associate them how ever you need. This way you will have more control over the data. In the end, what is generated by EF in the database will be a link table between Statuses and Types. Do you have an example of you entity mappings so we can see how you are defining your relationships?

Comment: Thanks, @DDiVita. I will think about this some more and try to implement, I will follow up with you.

Comment: Okay, so the problem with this approach is that it doesn't seem to account for the relationship with Type. I'm not sure if it is a true Parent/Child relationship. The way this code is written, every Type with a Status of On will have ChildStatuses of Success and Fail. But I need it to be unique to the Specific Type as well. So Type1 can have a Status of "On" with a SubStatus of 'Success' only. And Type2 can have a Status of "On" with Substatuses of "Success" and "Fail".

Comment: @JAck28, I guess you could only associate the Type with the child statuses and work you way up the tree. I'll update my answer and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, @DDiVita. Your solution worked out very nicely.